# imitate the slide/animate behavior of a drawer being opened/closed

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

This is the pen I have created: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/ogwqpX?editors=101

Before you click the orange arrow div I have set the id="sidebar" to display:none;

When you click the orange arrow div it moves 200px to the left side and the sidebar display property is set to 'auto'.

The whole animation is not what I want.

I want that the whole sidebarContainer + the sidebarHandle/sidebar moves to the left side by 200px starting from the location of the sidebarHandle. At the moment the animation starts from the right side of the sidebar thus the animation looks bad.

How can I get the behavior of flyout/drawer being opened and closed?

**HTML**

```
<div  id="view" style="height:400px;">
    <div style="height:100%;background:black;" class="col-xs-3">
        column 3
    </div>
    <div style="height:100%;background:red;" class="col-xs-4">
       column 4
    </div>
    <div id="availableSidebarColumn" style="padding:0;background:yellow;height:100%;" class="col-xs-1">

        <div class="sidebarClosed" id="sidebarContainer" style="position:absolute;z-index:10; display:table;height:100%;width:30px;background:green;">

                <div  id="sidebarHandle" style="border:1px solid black;cursor:pointer;background-color: orange;width:100%;display: table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align: middle;font-size:32px;" class="text-center glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
                </div>

               <div id="sidebar" style="display:none;border:1px solid black;background:orange;height:100%;width:200px">
                 <div style="background:lightblue;height:10%;">navigation</div>
                 <div style="background:lightgreen;height:90%;">content</div>
               </div>              
       </div>      

    </div>
    <div style="height:100%;background:pink;" class="col-xs-4">
       column 4
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
      $('#view').height(400);

        $('#sidebarHandle').click(function () {

               $('#sidebarHandle').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
               $('#sidebarContainer').animate({right:'200px'},350); // 200px is the width of the sidebar
               $('#sidebar').css('display', "auto");  

        });
   });
```

Comment: You need to set `$('#sidebarContainer').animate({right:'-200px'},350);`, not 200px. And btw, `auto` is not a valid value for the display property. Set it to `block` instead.

Comment: right: -200px did not help, now it moves to the right side when its opening...

Comment: In my current version of Firefox/Windows it moves to the right as expected.

Comment: If you want it to move to the left, that's what your original version did.

Comment: Yes... but its not what I want at all see my question :-)

Comment: You don't want it to move right, and you don't want it to move left either. So please try to explain clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Elisa so in other words, you want the sidebarhandle(vertical bar with '>') to stay put, and when you click on it, the menu should appear, another click it should hide? also the sidebarhandle(vertical bar with '>') should   move aswell?

Comment: @Crispy-George YES that way I would like to have it. Just like a drawer you pull of the desk and close the drawer into the desk. If thats not too hard. Also see my z-index I set because I do not want the whole layout to move/be influenced when the sidebar is opened.

Comment: @connexo YES I want to move it to the left but not in that way. I want that the sidebarhandle + sidebar move to the left by 200px starting at the position of the sidebarHandle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, when you click on that handle, some stuff should slide from the left to right, and vice-versa when you click on it again.

- remove the display none from the `#sidebar`
- some extra css will handle its visibility, width: 0 + overflow:hidden
- set a toggleClass between when its opened, to width: needed width, and when its closed, switch back to width: 0;
- and thats about it.

Maybe it could be done via js, like animate that width, in a certain amount of time, I've used `transition` prop to animate it.

I've added the extra css used, in the css tab, you can check out the **[demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwgrLJ)** and hopefully this will help you out

---

Ok, since you know the width of the drawer and the width of the trigger, you can set a width for its container. Given this situation, I've changed a bit of your original css, to position absolute, for both the trigger and the drawer, so I could animate the width, or left/right props. easier this way.

I've made 2 examples to illustrate this example, hopefully this time I got it right :) The markup structure is basically the same, only the id/class names differ(id names were too long to keep track of who and whats doing).

Check out the **[demos here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogwyXy)**, and let me know how it goes.

---

**Update v3**

The drawer was pushed to the right, because in my original example, I've set some margins between those 2 drawers, to better understand whats happening.

Now for the z-index issues, well its pretty simple, since the drawer was pushed 200px to the right, it would have fallen beneath its adjacent sibling, so you had to add some z-index, to invert their order.

Also the drawer had some static width set on it(I think 200 something px), however if you want it to be contained inside its parent, you can get the parents width, the set it to the drawer and it should be ok.

Check out the **[new pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaXdOp)**

Comment: That's what I'm getting from the OP so hopefully he marks it. It looks good

Comment: @Crispy Thats not what I want. I have this already look here: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/WbjNzY What I want is from RIGHT to LEFT just like opening a drawer.The handle must move by 200px to the left and the sidebar must follow the handle by 200px :-)

Comment: @EasyBB In my init question I wrote:"...moves to the left side by 200px ..." How can you get that wrong?

Comment: @Elisa yeah I think I got it, its been a long day :) anyway, regarding the css/markup that you currently have, can something be changed or should be build on it?

Comment: @Elisa check out the new demo and let me know how it goes

Comment: @Crispy-George Your latest pen is CRAZY AWESOME !!! Let me implement it today in my bootstrap column design and check its behavior. Then I give feedback again.

Comment: @Elisa oki, let me know how it went

Comment: See this pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/MYobdV Can you tell me why the sidebar is visible in the 4th bootstrap column and not the 3rd one? And why it is visible at all and only when the z-index:20000; is set?

Comment: Ok I had to scroll to the right side then its still there when the z-index is removed. But I need the z-index and it must be inside the the 3rd column. Actually it needs the z-index only I think when the drawer is opened. Else the animation goes into the background underneath the other columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69596/discussion-between-crispy-george-and-elisa).

Comment: I have it here: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/MYobdV The more I understand the more I can customize it! Thanks for the chat offer :-)

Comment: @Elisa yep I keep getting warnings 'please avoid extended discussions in comments ....'; anyway check out the new pen in the updated answer

Comment: @Crispy-George Thanks for new pen but thats not the behavior I need (you cant know I never told ya). But when you check my latest pen in the comment above everything seems fine for me now I gotta put it into prod code!

Comment: @Crispy-George Where is your css class 'opened'?

Comment: @Elisa uhm, well it's not in that pen? I used that to change the position of the trigger and content when you click on the trigger

Comment: ah doesnt matter I use the closed and my opened class to switch z-index which I have to do on the left-trigger! NO offense! I just found that empty class...

Comment: Yes Its working for me in my prod environment. I still have to LESSen the code and put similar values into one variable to easily maintain the sidebar. The problems I still have with z-index outside the sidebar overlapped by the z-index of the sidebar are my challenge now :-) Again thank you for the help. People like you make SO a warm place :-)

Comment: Maybe work with a lower z-index value? Like if the sidebar is under the next column, add a to the sidebar a z-index of say 10, and the column of 1 with pos. relative; Anyway, glad to help out, and happy that this issue is solved(most of it anyway) :)

Comment: @Crispy-George Just another question...the company I work for has an offshore partner in romania/cluj (5-6 hours from you away...) If you are interested in a developer job let me know , maybe we can arrange something. :-)

Comment: @Elisa Thanks alot for the offer, thats very kind of you! Currently I'm freelancing, and not really looking for a job atm, maybe in the future, who know how things turn out :) Anyway, many thanks again, its super kind of you to do that!